# Select a list item from dropdown to open modal? Should I use jquery/js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, select

I'm trying create a dropdown with a few list items, and when a user selects a certain "time" for example "later", triggering the later modal to open. (The original code is select/option but I have javascript converting it to ul/li for styling purposes.)

Here is the the list item code.

```
<ul class="select-options" style="display: none;">
   <li value="asap">Delivery ASAP</li>
   <li value="later">Delivery Later</li>
   <li value="catering">Catering</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the modal code.

```
    <div class="later-modal">
        <p>Select a time to deliver.</p>
    </div>

<div class="catering-modal">
        <p>Select a time to cater.</p>
    </div>
```

Should I use an if/else statement to open a modal? I'm not really sure what to do at this point. I'm also not using any bootstrap of any kind.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the drop-down to a real drop-down (select element).

Here is the solution:

```js
$('li').click(function(){
  $('.modal').hide();
  $('.' + $(this).attr('data-value') + '-modal').show();
  $('#dropdown').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

```css
label {
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid silver;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:2px;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding:2px;
  margin:0;
  border:1px solid silver;
  border-radius:5px;
  position:absolute;
}

li {
  margin:0;  
  cursor:pointer;
}

#dropdown {
  display:none;
}

.select-options {
  opacity:0;
  transition:all .2s ease;
}

#dropdown:checked + .select-options {
  opacity:1;  
}

.modal {
  display:none;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="dropdown">Choose time</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="dropdown" />

<ul class="select-options">
   <li data-value="asap">Delivery ASAP</li>
   <li data-value="later">Delivery Later</li>
   <li data-value="catering">Catering</li>
</ul>

<div class="modal later-modal">
  <p>Select a time to deliver.</p>
</div>

<div class="modal catering-modal">
  <p>Select a time to cater.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Even though it does open with the select/option, I have it changing to li in html. Maybe this will help? Is there any way to have it return to the li instead of the option? http://jsfiddle.net/utxeLb0b/ @moshfeu

Comment: @BeckyT I updated my code + I added some functionality for the "drop down like". If you not need it, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Iam sorry before I have copy bad block of code...try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#later").click(function() {
    $(".later-modal").toggle();
  });
  
  $("#catering").click(function() {
  $(".catering-modal").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="select-options" style="display: block;">
  <li value="asap">Delivery ASAP</li>
  <li id="later" value="later">Delivery Later</li>
  <li id="catering" value="catering">Catering</li>
</ul>

<div class="later-modal" style="display: none;">
  <p>Select a time to deliver.</p>
</div>

<div class="catering-modal" style="display: none;">
  <p>Select a time to cater.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to have the "later" value in list item to open instead selecting all li? @ZAJDAN

Comment: See my answer. This code is not so correctly and not generic.

Comment: a little bit I do not understand what you mean _ 'value in list item to open instead selecting all li?'_ @Becky T